# CSS transform animation in AbstractSafeHtmlCell

Tags: css, gwt

I'm currently working on a table where i can delete rows by switching into an editing state. When this state is set, each row has a "Delete" button. I want to animate this delete button when the mode is switched (analogous to the ios table functionality).

I achieved that the button appears/disappears when i switch the state, but the animation does not work. When i debug the GUI in the browser and when i switch for e.g. the left position property, the animation works as expected.

So i guess that switching state in code, which calls again the render method, creates again a safehtml string, now with the new style classes (corresponding to the state), does not trigger css animation, but just replaces the html and renders it as specified by css.

How could i achieve to trigger the css animation by "changing" (not replacing) the css property?

Edit: a hover state on these divs works with animation, which supports my theory that writing the html string just replaces the html without triggering the animation...

Below the code in my render method:

```
@Override
public void render(Context context, DashboardListTableRecord object, SafeHtmlBuilder shb) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<div");
    sb.append(" class='");
    sb.append(RESOURCES.style().nameAndDeleteBtnContainer());
    sb.append("'>");

    sb.append("<div");
    sb.append(" id='");
    sb.append("deleteButton");
    sb.append(" '");
    sb.append(" class='");
    sb.append(RESOURCES.style().deleteBtnInvisible());
    if(this.isEditMode) {
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(RESOURCES.style().deleteBtn());
    }
    sb.append("'>");

    sb.append("Delete");
    sb.append("</div>");

    sb.append("<div");
    sb.append(" id='");
    sb.append("valueLabel");
    sb.append(" '");
    sb.append(" class='");
    sb.append(RESOURCES.style().valueLabel());
    if(this.isEditMode) {
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(RESOURCES.style().valueLabelEdit());
    }
    sb.append("'>");
    sb.append(object.getDisplayname());
    sb.append("</div>");
    sb.append("</div>");
    shb.appendHtmlConstant(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Note: your code isn't "safe": what if `object.getDisplayname()` contain unsanitized HTML? Use `SafeHtmlTemplate` to build your `SafeHtml`, possibly coupled with `HtmlSanitizer`.

Comment: thx for input, will have a look on this